# How can i make a specific part of a material glow?

Tags: emission

I am trying to create a model of the alphabet 'A'. is there a way to make only the blue color glow? leaving the pink as it is. I tried using 2 different shaders, principled bsdf and emission shader and then joining both with a mix shader but the result was awful.[image]

[image]

Comment: yes, mixing the 2 colors in a Mix Shader is the way to go, that said it will only glow if you use an effect like Bloom in Eevee or Glare in the Compositor

Comment: I only want the blue portion to glow.

Comment: You probably need to use the Compositor and 2 separate layers, one for the blue zone to which you'll give a Glare effect?

Comment: if you don't mind, could you help me with a step by step process on how to go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use this material setup:

[image]

compositor nodes:

[image]

to get this:

[image]

Of course you can change the "greater than" threshold and the "multiply" value to tweak your result, as well as changing values in the glare node.

[image]

Comment: It did work. Thank you

Comment: Glad I could help.